# Limit drag area for a shape with Plotly.js

Tags: d3.js, draggable, drag, shapes, plotly.js

I want to be able to do something similar with this, but with Plotly.js:
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1557377

The idea is to pause the moving of the shape while a condition, and after that condition is not 'true' continue to move the shape again.